# Does skb_unref() behave as it's meant to?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, network-programming, linux-device-driver

**Foreword:**

If you are familiar with the linux kernel buffers for managing network packets, as known as **`sk_buff`**, then you are probably know the function that frees the skb: `__kfree_skb()`

From my understanding with the `sk_buff` code and API, the `__kfree_skb()` is the function that frees the `sk_buff`. It's an internal helper function and theoretically user shouldn't call it - the user should call one of its wrapper functions, like `kfree_skb()` or `consume_skb()` (or some other safe wrapper).
Before calling `__kfree_skb()`, the wrapper functions should check and decrease the `sk_buff` refcount, and if it reaches 0, the wrapper function can call `__kfree_skb()` to free the `sk_buff`. Some of the wrappers do it by themselves, and other just call `skb_unref()` (that has been added to the mainline about 3 years ago).

Hope you are still with me. Here I come to the point. I've recently noticed that `skb_unref()` doesn't do what I thought it should do. Up to the latest release of linux kernel v5.8, `skb_unref()` looks like this:

```
/**
 * skb_unref - decrement the skb's reference count
 * @skb: buffer
 *
 * Returns true if we can free the skb.
 */
static inline bool skb_unref(struct sk_buff *skb)
{
    if (unlikely(!skb))
        return false;
    if (likely(refcount_read(&skb->users) == 1))
        smp_rmb();
    else if (likely(!refcount_dec_and_test(&skb->users)))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

**The Problem:**

- After I read the code, I've noticed that if `refcount_read` returns 1, we won't decrease `skb->users` to 0, but the function does returns `true`.
- It means, that if `refcount_read` returns 1, `skb_unref()` tells `kfree_skb()` (or some other wrapper function that using `skb_unref()`) that it can free the `skb` (but it doesn't decrease `skb->users` to 0), and if the last user that actually frees the skb doesn't bother to set the `skb` to `NULL` after calling `kfree_skb()`, then when some other user will check this `skb` refcount, it may accidentally try to free it again!
- I've also made sure I'm not mistaken by reading the code, and I just tried to call `kfree_skb()` twice, and everything crashed...
- Am I wrong? Perhaps I don't understand how to use `kfree_skb()/skb_unref()` correctly? I just wonder how the hell things still work if `kfree_skb()/skb_unref()` don't behave as they should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this *was* a long time ago [explained in a comment](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/2.4.31/source/include/linux/skbuff.h#L279) (LOL at the spelling mistake):

```c
/*
 * If users==1, we are the only owner and are can avoid redundant
 * atomic change.
 */
```

Long story short: it's just a subtle optimization.

If the refcount is 1, this means that you are the *only* owner of the resource, therefore you can safely avoid wasting time atomically decrementing the refcount, and just proceed to free it.

> if the last user that actually frees the skb doesn't bother to set the `skb` to `NULL` after calling `kfree_skb()`, then when some other user will check this `skb` refcount, it may accidentally try to free it again!

If the refcount is 1, you are the *only* user, who else is going to call `kfree_skb()`? Nobody but you.

> I just tried to call `kfree_skb()` twice, and everything crashed

What else do you expect? The Linux kernel code is not your babysitter, you can of course cause a crash if you double-free something. It may print some warning before dying, but that's about it. This is true with basically any kind of allocation. Just like in any other C program, you must make sure that you are only freeing memory once.

---

PS: the behavior of `kfree_skb()` has always been the same that you see now, even before v2.6, the only difference is that some of its code was "recently" moved to `skb_unref()` (in v4.13).

Comment: I guess the comment from the latest kernel versions mislead me: "Drop a reference to the buffer and free it if the usage count has hit zero". But I must say I think I understand the SKB mechanism much better after your explanation. 10X!!! So from my understanding, if I allocates SKB, then I must be the one that call kfree_skb(), and if I want to pass it to a different layer, then this layer must call skb_get() (or to copy it) if it doesn't want me to release it yet (and when this layer done with the SKB it should also call kfree_skb()).

Comment: @J.M. yes, I would say your understanding is correct